# pendulum on a string problem, involving finding the lagrangian and moment of inertia

Tags: classical-mechanics, euler-lagrange-equation

First see the picture below for the problem.

[image: The problem]

My attempt is below

Part (1) 
For the moment of inertia i calculated that $$I=\frac{1}{3}ml^2$$
this is mainly from using resources online since i have no idea how to calculate it it was confusing me because in some texts they've written it as an intergral but i couldn't find any examples for systems similar to this, i know that the center of mass for the rod $cm$ is when $$cm=\frac{l}{2}l$$ ?

For part (2) i'm struggling on choosing an appropriate coordinate system to use? I have been trying to use polar coordinates but it is too hard, because i don't know how to include the rotational inertia in the formula for finding the kinetic energy, i know that $$T=\frac{1}{2}mv^2$$ where t is the kinetic energy,but how can one calculate v in this question?

for part (3) i found that the potential energy is $$mg(1-cos\theta)$$ but i dont think this is correct either because i havent been able to figure out what coordinate system to use for the problem.

i know that the lagrangian is given by $$L=T-U$$

i havent been able to attempt part 5 or 6 as of yet so i dont really need any information regarding them yet, i just want to know and understand how to attempt the first three since it would help with the revision that i am doing, none of the examples we have done in class have been similar, so i'm quite lost.

i have been using the following textbooks to help but to no prevail

(1) classical mechanics by john r taylor.
(2) schaums outline series lagrangian dynamics (the problems in this book are a lot more advanced than the ones given in lectures)

any help or direction would be extremely appreciated as i'm quite stuck.

Comment: The most natural coordinate system is hinted by the picture. It is $(\theta_1, \theta_2)$

Answer (score 1):

The distance between the center of the rod and the point of suspension is 
$$d = l \sqrt{\frac{5}{4} + \cos(\theta_2 - \theta_1)}$$
Use parallel axis theorem to find $$I = \dfrac{1}{12}ml^2 + md^2 = \left(\frac{4}{3} +\cos(\theta_2 - \theta_1) \right)ml^2$$

Comment: how did u calculate d? i've heared of the parallel axis theorem before just didnt realise i needed it here , thanks!

Comment: It might be helpful to see this if you redraw the picture showing $\theta_2$ to be greater than $\theta_1$. Construct a triangle whose sides are of length $l, \dfrac{l}{2}, d$ , with the angle opposite to $d$ being equal to $\pi - (\theta_2 - \theta_1)$. Now use the law of cosines https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_cosines .

Comment: okay this makes sense now, how would we include this when finding the kinetic and potential energies?

Comment: note is $\theta_2>\theta_1$? because from the original diagram they look the same if not  $\theta_1>\theta_2$